# How can I create an array of UIButtons/(UIImageViews) that appear after the last one was pressed

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I wasn't sure how to search for the answer to this question so I figured I would try my luck over here.

To put this in short, I have a UIView and created a UIButton programmatically along with a UIImageView added to the button as a subview and what happens is, when I press on the button, it allows me to add an image and it gets stored over the button.

So my question is: Once that is completed, how can I make it that another button/ImageView will appear in the view, next to the first button (or after it fills the screen to the right, appear in the 2nd row, 1st column) etc

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UICollectionView` as pointed out by @Bernahard Harrer or you could use the following code. This code adds only two buttons. In case, you need more buttons or an array of buttons, implement the following code and calculate the size of the previously added button, as height/width of `button1` is calculated for adding `button2`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self addButtons];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void) addButtons
{
    UIView *view = [self view];
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button1 sizeToFit];
[button2 sizeToFit];


CGFloat combinedWidth = (button1.frame.size.width) + (button2.frame.size.width) ;

//checking if combined width of both buttons is more than 320
if (combinedWidth>320) {
    CGFloat button1height = button1.frame.size.height;
    button1height = button1height + 10;
    [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(button2.frame.origin.x, (button2.frame.origin.y + button1height), button2.frame.size.width, button2.frame.size.width)];
} else {
    //if combined width of both buttons is less than or equal to 320
    //this will place the buttons adjacent to each other.
    //The code may be modified accordingly if to add some distance between them
    CGFloat button1width = button1.frame.size.width;
    [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake((button1.frame.origin.x+button1width), button2.frame.origin.y, button2.frame.size.width, button2.frame.size.height)];
}

[view addSubview:button1];
[view addSubview:button2];
}@end
```

Comment: @D34thSt4lker : I have added the images to buttons as background, not as subview. In either case, this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a UICollectionView for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController (){

    NSInteger x;
    NSInteger y;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    x = 4;y=100;


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (IBAction)addViews:(id)sender {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 10);

    int offset = 30;

    x = (frame.origin.x + frame.size.width + offset);

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    if (view.center.x+view.frame.size.width > 320) {
        y +=20;
        x = 4;
    }
    [view setFrame:frame];

    [self.view addSubview:view];



}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working for what I am trying to do... Just making sure its picking up everything I need